# How to change the queuing/stacking requests behaviour of Sanic

Tags: python, http, sanic

## Good day all

I'm tagging Sanic because that is what I'm using in my web app, but I'm not sure if this behaviour is due to Sanic or something underlying (like asyncio or even the network interface).

Please let me know if I need to write a quick example showing what I mean, my application is quite large so I can't share that here, but I think my problem is simple enough to explain.

I have a simple web application in Python using the Sanic framework. For my purposes, I actually need a server which is synchronous. As such, none of my endpoint functions are async, and I explicitly start my Sanic app with one worker.
This is because, when I send the server a number of requests, I need them to be performed in the order which they were sent.
However this does not happen.

Some of my requests take a lot of calculation, so they're not immediate. Meaning that consequent requests arrive while it is still processing.

In other words, imagine that I send 4 requests one after each other. Request 1 takes a few seconds to calculate, meaning that requests 2-4 arrive while request 1 is still being processed. What I want to happen is that requests are processed in order:

Request 1
Request 2
Request 3
Request 4

But what happens is that requests are processed out of order, in fact, after the first, it seems random:

Request 1
Request 3
Request 2
Request 4

So is there a way to force it to execute requests in order? Preferably at a high level (Sanic) ?

I've looked around but have not seen anyone talking about this behaviour. I suppose this is a rare case as my server is not RESTful and not stateless.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you need responses in order, Sanic might not be the solution. Just because your handlers are not async doesn't mean anything about the rest of the lifecycle, all of which IS async. Do you also have any Middleware? Sanic cannot guarantee response order, unless you built in some sort of queue mechanism and did this on your own.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the response.
I do not have any middleware. I wondered if it would fix my problem, but didn't want to go down that route until I was sure.
I'm not married to Sanic. Could you suggest another framework which might be better suited? Perhaps Flask or aiohttp?

Comment: Any async framework will behave this way. The issue is really at the web server level, not the framework. Web servers are designed to handle multiple requests simultaneously to increase throughput. If your use case is simple enough, you might want to give it a go to build a server custom to this requirement.